# OpenCV: Get 3D coordinates from triangulatePoints

Tags: c++, opencv

I' trying to get cloud of points from two stereo images using OpenCV, but I can't get coordinates.

1. I found points coordinates using Optical Flow
2. I found projection matrixes for cameras.

> ```
> Mat RT1;<br>
> hconcat(R, T1, RT1);<br>
> Mat P1 = C*RT1;<br>
> ```

R is 3x3 rotation matrix, T is 3x1 transform matrix (column), P1 - projection matrix.

3. I pass them to triangulatePoints function

> ```
> triangulatePoints(P1, P2, leftPoints, rightPoints, out);
> ```

P1 and P2 is 3x4 projection matrix (Mat_<double>).
leftPoints and rightPoints is std::vector of Point2f.
What is out? It should be 1xN matrix of 4D coords. Is this Vec4f?

I am trying get coordinates

> ```
> for (int i = 0; i < out.cols; i++)
> {
>   Vec4f vec = out.at<Vec4f>(0, i);
>   float w = vec[3];
>   stream << "v " << vec[0] / w << " " << vec[1]/w << " " << vec[2]/w << "\n";
> }
> ```

But I have two problems:

- This cycle throw exception (works for small i, about 20% of out.cols)

> OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (dims <= 2 && data && (unsigned)i0 <
>   (unsigned)si ze.p[0] && (unsigned)(i1 * DataType<_Tp>::channels) <
>   (unsigned)(size.p[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQ8dd.jpg) * cha nnels()) &&
>   ((((sizeof(size_t)<<28)|0x8442211) >> ((DataType<_Tp>::depth) & ((1 <<
>   3) - 1))*4) & 15) == elemSize1()) in cv::Mat::at, file
>   c:\opencv\build\includ e\opencv2\core\mat.inl.hpp, line 89

I think this is some kind of Index Out Range Exception

- Result is very strange:
  [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQ8dd.jpg)

So, I am doing something wrong. How correctly work with this function and get 3D coordinates of points? I'll hope you can help me.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand exactly your approach in getting the coordinates.

As far as I see, you should not be accessing elements like

```
out.at<Vec4f>(0, i);
```

Instead, do it like this:

```
float x = out.at<float>(0, i);
float y = out.at<float>(1, i);
float z = out.at<float>(2, i);
float w = out.at<float>(3, i);
stream << "v " << x << " " << y << " " << z << "\n";
```

Or use `double`... depending whether you `out` is of type `CV_32F` or `CV_64F`.

Here is how I do it:

```
Mat points3DHomogeneous;
triangulatePoints(projectionMatrixL, projectionMatrixR, pointsL, pointsR, points3DHomogeneous);
```

`projectionMatrixL`:

[image]

`projectionMatrixR`:

[image]

`pointsL`:

```
    700 250
    200 300
    600 350
    400 400
    500 450
    600 500
    700 550
    800 600
    150 650
    1000 700
```

`pointsR`:

```
    690 250
    180 300
    590 350
    385 400
    495 450
    575 500
    691 550
    782 600
    120 650
    960 700
```

`points3DHomogeneous` is the result:

[image]